# MySQL not inserting data from one column

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert a data into a database. This is the code that I am using. It inserts all the data except the image(`Pic`).

```
public function insert($hey){

    try {

        $hey = $this->db->query("INSERT INTO addmember(Pic,Firstname,Lastname,Age,Gender,Phonenumber,Location,Member,Department) VALUES('".$hey['pic']."','".$hey['fname']."','".$hey['lname']."','".$hey['age']."','".$hey['gender']."','".$hey['phone']."','".$hey['loc']."','".$hey['group']."','".$hey['department']."')");

    } catch (PDOException $e) {

        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to do a print_r($hey); to see if pic actually contains something? Did you checked the type of column in database?

Comment: yes pls its still ot working

Comment: can you explain what the column type and size is?

Comment: What error message is showing up?

Comment: Array ( [id] => 7 [Pic] => 20151222_161552.jpg [Firstname] => Allan [Lastname] => Aikins [Age] => 0 [Gender] => [Phonenumber] => 209007684 [Location] => Accra [Member] => member

Comment: this is what i got when i used print_r

Comment: varchar255 @ RamRaider

Comment: your key in array is "Pic", but in your code you are using "pic" (with lowercase)

Comment: There is nothing showing @Robert

Comment: Please when i check the database too instead of pic.jpg it is stored as an array

Answer (score 0):

You're indexing the array $hey wrong. ($hey["pic"] is incorrect according to your array dump)

This should work:

```
public function insert($hey){

    try {

        $hey = $this->db->query("INSERT INTO addmember(Pic,Firstname,Lastname,Age,Gender,Phonenumber,Location,Member,Department) VALUES('".$hey['Pic']/* this is where hte error was occuring */."','".$hey['fname']."','".$hey['lname']."','".$hey['age']."','".$hey['gender']."','".$hey['phone']."','".$hey['loc']."','".$hey['group']."','".$hey['department']."')");

    } catch (PDOException $e) {

        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

On a side note, why are you not binding the inputs?

Comment: $data = array('pic' => $pic,
   'fname' => $firstname,
   'lname' => $lastname,
   'age' => $age,
   'gender' => $gender,
   'phone' => $phonenumber,
   'loc' => $location,
   'group' => $group,
   'department' => $deparment
   
);                                                                                                                                                 was using $hey['pic '] cos of the above code

Comment: its an array i created so that i can use it the $hey[]

Comment: at the top of your function, please put `die(var_dump($hey));` and paste the response.

Comment: Undefined variable: hey in C:\xampp\htdocs\churchmanagement\viewallmem.php on line 318
NULL